# Race condition in shared_ptr doesn't happen

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, smart-pointers

Why there is no any race condition in my code?
Due to source here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

> If multiple threads of execution access the same shared_ptr without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur;

```
class base
{
public:
    std::string val1;
};

class der : public base
{
public:
    std::string val2;
    int val3;
    char val4;
};

int main()
{
    std::mutex mm;
    std::shared_ptr<der> ms(new der());

    std::thread t1 = std::thread([ms, &mm]() {
        while (1)
        {
        //std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mm);

            std::string some1 = ms->val2;
            int some2 = ms->val3;
            char some3 = ms->val4;
            ms->val2 = "1232324";
            ms->val3 = 1232324;
            ms->val4 = '1';
        }
    });

    std::thread t2 = std::thread([ms, &mm]() {
        while (1)
        {
            //std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mm);

            std::string some1 = ms->val2;
            int some2 = ms->val3;
            char some3 = ms->val4;
            ms->val2 = "123435";
            ms->val3 = 123435;
            ms->val4 = '3';
        }
    });

    std::shared_ptr<base> bms = ms;
    std::thread t3 = std::thread([bms]() {
        while (1)
        {
            bms->val1 = 434;
        }
    });

    while (1)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a data race in your code.  The compiler is not going to give you an error though, it simply produces undefined code.

Comment: You have data races **and** race conditions, they are different. However, `shared_ptr` in your example has none, it's all on `der`

Comment: @Passer By but what about `operator->` in `std::shared_ptr` over there can be race condition. As I understand to avoid it I should use `std::atomic_load` and get copy of the `std::shated_ptr` to use in another `std::thread`.

Comment: You copied your `shared_ptr`s into your lambdas, they can't be a data race/race condition.

Comment: To be clear, the control block of `shared_ptr` is designed to be functional in multithreaded environments, Herb Sutter even gave a talk including some of it once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data races do not yield compilation failure; they yield undefined behavior. That behavior *could* be "works fine". Or "appears to work fine but subtly breaks something 12 minutes later". Or "immediately fails."

Just because code *appears* to work doesn't mean it actually does. This is more true for threading code than any other kind.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use valgrind tool - helgrind.
It is very hard to find race conditions sometimes when debugging multi-threading programs.
To run this tool you need to have valgrind on your computer and run it using:

```
valgrind --tool=helgrind ./Your_Complied_File arg1 arg2 ...
```